# Feed multiple sequential input to stdin python

Tags: python, stdin

Is there a way I can feed multiple inputs into stdin, to be readily parsed when `input()` is called? I'm trying to autograde submissions by students, and their code is using the `input()` function. But this is quite tiring to test one by one, and am seeking to do it automatically.

I can currently either prepend code after the students code, or after it (`<MORE CODE HERE>`)

Ideally, the input to stdin would be like `Image1.jpg <enter> 2 <enter> Y <enter> 3 <enter> N` and it runs that in the code.

Here's a sample student submission, with the places in which i can prepend / append code

```
<MORE CODE HERE>
def question1():
    YN = 'Y'
    function_dict = { '1':action_1, '2':action_2, '3':action_3}

    filename = input('Please enter the file name')
    while(YN=='Y'):
        print('Please select an operation you want to perform')
        print('1. action_1')
        print('2. action_2')
        print('3. action_3')
        choice = input('What is your choice?')
        function_dict[choice](filename)
        YN = input('Do you want to continue? (Y/N)')

<MORE CODE HERE>
question1()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a standardized filename for the projects like .py, and an expected format and output for the questions, you could define a function to call a single project with the EasyProcess python module and then iterate for all projects matching a particular filename pattern in a folder and confirm if the out put is correct.

Comment: This isn't solving my problem though? My problem is i want to automate test cases for a particular file, using stdin

Comment: I don't understand is why you need to use stdin to automate the test cases. Could you clarify?

Comment: If you look at the code, The function has no arguments. it takes in values from `input()`. hence, to test it, i need to input stuff to stdin.